# Deep Linking With Firebase - Enable Force Refresh (efr=1) Parameter Not Working With Twitter

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

The enable force refresh parameter (efr=1) for Firebase isn't working properly with my Firebase Deep-Links. It works perfectly for Facebook, but if I include this parameter in the deep link url and share to twitter it redirects to the app store instead of within the app. Basically...

**https://example.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com** - works and redirects the user from Twitter to the correct page within the app.

**https://example.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com&efr=1** - redirects users to the app store no matter what.

Anybody else having this issue?

Comment: and what if you try encoding the ampersand: `https://example.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com&amp;efr=1`

Comment: Andrew, this is the reason why App preview page exists. By specifying efr=1 you disabling App preview page and losing benefits provided by this page. Details about App preview https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews

Comment: Any suggestion on how can i pass ```efr=1``` in dynamic link info object ... please this paste bin https://pastebin.com/iYWBVXbW